# Keras: How to Combine two Layers, but not Elementwise, into bigger shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

So I want to combine multiple Layers into 1 in my keras-nn. The difference is, that I don't want to combine them like in the `Add()`-layer, but I want to combine multiple Layers with different shape yet the same dimension into one bigger layer, whose shape is the sum of the input-layers. Here is my very crudly draw structure (The Dots represent a node):

[image: Overview]

And here is some code how i would imagine it:

```
[IN]
input_1 = Input(shape=(4,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(6,))

combined = Combined()([input_1, input_2])
print(input_1.shape, input_2.shape, input_3.shape)


[OUT]
(4,)  (6,)  (10,)
```

There might be already a Layer in keras that has the functionality, but I browsed the Internet for some time and couldn’t find any answer to this problem

~Okaghana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `Concatenate` layer:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(4,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(6,))

combined = Concatenate()([input_1, input_2])
print(input_1.shape, input_2.shape, combined.shape)
```

This outputs:

```
(?, 4) (?, 6) (?, 10)
```

Comment: Mh... That's strange.
I was pretty sure that I already tried Concatenate() and it gave me an error, but apparently I didn't.

Thanks